# Calculating probability limit

Tags: limits, statistics, expected-value, probability-limit-theorems

I tried taking conditional probability on $\epsilon,$ to change the question in a form where we are taking plim of $\mu^2$ plus some noise. However, I'm having difficulties showing the noise part formally. Thank you in advance![enter image description here][1]

Question: Suppose $(x_i , \epsilon_i)$ ~ iid  with $E(x_i) = \mu, var(x_i)= \sigma^2$, and $E[\epsilon_i|x_i]=x_i,$ Find the $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ $n^{-1} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n  x_ie_i$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $\ (x_i,\epsilon_i)\ $ are independent and identically distributed, then so are $\ x_i\epsilon_i\ $, and
\begin{align}
E\big[x_i\epsilon_i\big]&=E\big[E[x_i\epsilon_i|x_i]\big]\\
&=E\big[x_iE[\epsilon_i|x_i]\big]\\
&=E\big[x_i^2\big]\\
&=\sigma^2+\mu^2\ .
\end{align}
[The strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) will therefore give you your limit.

Comment: Just to be sure by the strong law of large numbers, I can say that when n tends to infinity then the sample average converges to the expected value. Thus, the answer to the      
   lim n→∞ (1/n)∑ (x_i)(e_i)  = sigma^2 +mu^2

Comment: Yes, that's right.